# How to set Specific (dummy) image on the whole category products. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, frontend, products

Actually I add many products in my Magento 2 but we still dont have any images for that products so I want to set the a *Dummy image* on whole category products e.g like on *Men categories* products I want to set `xyz.jpg` image and for *Women categories* I want to set `abc.jpg` image.... how is it will be possible?

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-upload-placeholders-in-magento-2.html This link might help you

Comment: Thank you soo much Sir it works

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create one root file and paste below code in that file and run file in browser or you can also create module

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
set_time_limit(0);
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap     = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$appState->setAreaCode('frontend');
$dir = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList');

$categoryId = 2; // here you can assign men or women category category id
$collection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')->load($categoryId)->getProductCollection();
$imagePath = $dir->getPath('media')."/yourimage.jpg"; // Your image should be on pub/media path
$imageType = ['image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'];

if($collection->getSize()) {
    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        if($product->getId()) {
            if(file_exists($imagePath)) {
                $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());
                $product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, $imageType, false, false);
                $product->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you!